# Vue v-on:click change it to load or mouse over event

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get `v-bind:value` on to function `reservationBy()` as load event instead of  `v_on:click`event. Right now it passes the value when I click on it only.

Is there a way to make it load automatically or use mouse over event? I even try to use v-on:load and v-on:focus event but it did not work.

**View**

```
<div id="app">
   <input v-bind:value="2" v-on:click="reservationBy"/>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {

  },
  methods: {

    reservationBy: function(e) { 
        var peopleBookedId = e.target.value;
        console.log(peopleBookedId);

  }
  }
})
```

Here is example on `JSFIDDLE`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/yz0p1vqL/4/

Comment: using v-model is not an option?

Comment: @AJT82 what you mean by using v-model. Got confuse on that

Answer (score 0):

`@mouseover` and `@mouseleave` will do the job.

```
<input v-bind:value="2" @mouseover="reservationBy"/>

or

<input v-bind:value="2" @mouseleave="reservationBy"/>
```

Comment: I removed click and added mouseover. But mouseover event runs only on click as well.

Answer (score 0):

If using v-model is not an option (that would be the easiest way), and you want to execute the function when component is rendered, you can use `ref` and access value in mounted hook:

```
<input ref="myInputRef" :value="2" />
```

Script:

```
mounted: function() {
  console.log(this.$refs.myInputRef.value);
}
```